# eslint unnecessarily warning "promise/no-nesting" with Firestore transactions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have Firestore data structured as follows:

[image]

I want to runTransaction() on the trend_score child. My function was working prior to adding the second .then(result =>, meaning now that I added another method to the cloud function, I am getting an error:

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.handler = functions.firestore.document('/Polls/{pollId}/responses/{userId}').onCreate((data, context) => {
                  const answerSelected = data.data().answer;

                  const answerRef = admin.firestore().doc(`Polls/${context.params.pollId}/answers/${answerSelected}`);
                  const voteCountRef = admin.firestore().doc(`Polls/${context.params.pollId}`);
                  const trendScoreRef = admin.firestore.doc(`Polls/${context.params.pollId}/trend_score`);

                   return admin.firestore().runTransaction(t => {
                               return t.get(answerRef)
                                   .then(doc => {
                                       if (doc.data()) {
                                           t.update(answerRef, { vote_count: doc.data().vote_count + 1 });
                                       }
                                   })
                           }).then(result => {
                               return admin.firestore().runTransaction(t => {
                                           return t.get(voteCountRef)
                                               .then(doc => {
                                                   if (doc.data()) {
                                                       t.update(voteCountRef, {vote_count:doc.data().vote_count+1});
                                                   }
                                               });
                                        });
                           //starting with this set, I believe this code has caused the issue
                           }).then(result => {
                               return admin.firestore().runTransaction(t => {
                                           return t.get(trendScoreRef)
                                                .then(doc => {
                                                  if (doc.data()) {
                                                      t.update(trendScoreRef, {trend_score:doc.data().trend_score+1});
                                                  }
                                                });
                                        });
           });
```

> > Error

```
     1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/troychuinard/.npm/_logs/2018-11-10T02_02_56_229Z-debug.log

    Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/etVwy.png
```

Comment: Your question isn't showing all the relevant output from the console, but I can tell you right now that eslint is complaining that you have nested `then` callbacks, which is considered bad style and prone to bugs.

Comment: Got it, so instead of adding the additional then callbacks, should I just add another t.update to the bottom of the first callback? Or would best practice be a separate function? Essentially, I want to update 2 locations with 1 method

Comment: Just add it as another `then` in the chain, as shown in the dup.

Comment: Isn't that what I did essentially?

Comment: No, you have nested `then` callbacks **inside** other `then`s rather **after** them.

Comment: Actually, that might not be a problem for transactions.  Could you take a close look at the eslint error message that you didn't show here and update your question to include it/

Comment: I may have been missing a bracket

Comment: Yeah, and if you add that, I bet you'll get more for promise/no-nesting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183402/discussion-between-tccpg288-and-doug-stevenson).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you resolve the syntax error, eslint is warning you that you have nested promises.  This is normally not good, but since they are nested inside a transaction callback, there's actually not a problem here.  You can disable that warning at the line where eslint finds it by adding this comment to the end of the lines that it warns you about:

```
return t.get(answerRef) // eslint-disable-line promise/no-nesting
    .then(...)
```